# Php how to use Explode in a sentence

Tags: php

I am thinking a way to do this. I want to get some text in a sentence.

This is a sample of $item_title in database:

**cat1 + sub1 of cat1 + test 1 of sub1 of cat1**

All i want to do is  get the sentence starting from first ' + '

In this case i want to have:

**sub1 of cat1 + test 1 of sub1 of cat1**

```
$pieces = explode(" + ", $item_title);
$idonotneed = $pieces[0]; // cat1
```

Comment: but the sentence changes all the time. i do not know how many $pieces i would have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$pieces = explode(" + ", $item_title, 2);`

You can pass a third parameter, that represents the max amount of segments you'd like to receive.

`$pieces[0]` will the be the first segment; `pieces[1]` the rest.

Comment: +1 I didn't think about that. I think this is a better solution than mine.

Comment: will pieces[1] always be the full sentence even if there are 5, 6 ' + ' in the $item_title

Comment: @baris22 yes, except if there is no + in the sentence, then only `$pieces[0]` will exist, so you might need to check the count/isset

Answer (score 1):

```
$pieces = explode(' + ', $item_title);
array_shift($pieces);
$wanted = implode(' + ', $pieces);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/^.*?\+ /', '', $item_title);
```

It's basically removing anything from the start of the string up until a + and a space are encountered... If there is no + followed by a space, it will return the whole sentence

Breaking down the regular expression:

- `.*?` Match any character (non greedy, will explain in a sec).
- `\+ /` A plus sign, followed by a space (added the `/` closing delimiter here otherwise the space doesn't show up.

Without the `?` to make the first part non greedy, it would match the last `+`.

If the regular expression doesn't match anything, then nothing is replaced and the whole string will be returned.

Comment: will this always match my sentence?

Comment: I won't -1, but really: why? There are other options, != regular expressions, that are faster and work like a charm. Why should you make your code so unreadable?

Comment: @baris22 see cbrandolino's answer, it is a simpler solution.

Comment: @cbrandolino, I suggested this as I didn't like the explode/implode solutions being given, didn't think about your solution.

Comment: Uh, now I feel guilty for the harsh comment ^^

Comment: @cbrandolino haha, no worries I usually prefer to go to non regex solutions when possible. Unless there is a nice performance/simplicity gain.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with **strpos** and **substr** as well.

```
$text = "cat1 + sub1 of cat1 + test 1 of sub1 of cat1";
$pos = strpos($text, '+');
echo substr($text, $pos+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for `explode()` or regular expressions.

```
$wanted = substr($item_title, strpos($item_title, '+') + 1);
```

Or:

```
$wanted = substr(strstr($item_title, '+'), 1);
```